# Prevent NetworkManager from setting ~. search domain per-link on systemd-resolved

Tags: dns, networkmanager, systemd-resolved

I'm trying to use the DNS over at `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` in their capacity as DNS over TLS providers, but NetworkManager somehow manages to set `~.` as search domain on the connections it sets up. That causes all the DNS queries to be funneled over the specific interface's DHCP-resolved DNS instead of the global DNS I configured:

```
Link 3 (wlo1)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6 mDNS/IPv4 mDNS/IPv6
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: yes
  DNSOverTLS setting: opportunistic
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.10.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.10.1
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      lan
```

I find the `lan` domain useful for local devices, so I can't simply disable the per-link DNS settings outright, but I can't find anyway to make NetworkManager not set `~.` there. It's not part of the `resolv.conf` modifications either:

```
[user@machine ~]$ cat /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search lan
nameserver 192.168.10.1
```

I need to make either NM not set any search domain except `lan` or make per-link configuration a fallback when global configurations doesn't work. Though the latter is probably quite unrealistic prospect.

Comment: I too am trying to figure out how to get rid of that `~.` entry. As a workaround, you can set `Domains=lan` in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, but there's a downside: it will search `lan` even when your `wlo1` interface is down.

Comment: It turns out that my problem was caused by `/etc/resolv.conf` pointing to the wrong file (`/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` when it should be `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`). Changing the symlink fixed it—no need to edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which version of NetworkManager implemented the change, but the problem has since been fixed with the current versions of NM.